# integration by parts on hypersurfaces

Tags: manifolds, curvature, integration-by-parts

Can anyone please help me with the understanding and proof of the statement found in
[Theorem 2.10](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-pPKOiIvPAhWJOhoKHX-2BpAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.warwick.ac.uk%2Fstaff%2FC.M.Elliott%2FDziEll13a.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH_YS8qug4GceDAKuFrHnUuHGhCFg&sig2=o4SZMJSNkAchEdSoARb-VQ)

Theorem: 
Assuming that $\Gamma$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, n = 1,2$ with smooth boundary $\partial \Gamma$ and that $f \in C^1(\overline{\Gamma}).$ Then 
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Gamma} \nabla_\Gamma f \, dA  = \int_{\Gamma} f H \nu \, dA + \int_{\partial \Gamma} f \mu \, ds,
\end{equation}
where μ denotes the co-normal vector which is normal to ∂Γ and tangent to
Γ, $\nu$ is the unit normal and $\nabla_\Gamma f= \nabla f - (\nabla f \cdot \nu )\nu$ and the curvature $H = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\partial_i \nu_i.$

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud , i want to proof that the right-hand-side holds using the definition of the tangential gradient.

Comment: your question is not clear. you have to reform it

Comment: @As, is it ok now?